# OAuth 2.0 Implicit Grant flow - Read calendar API returns 403

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, single-page-application, microsoft-identity-platform

Can anyone help me to figure out solution for the below problem?

Summary: 
I am getting 403 for Microsoft Graph Calendar Read API.

Detail 
I am using microsoft identity platform with implicit grant flow mechanism to log user from his microsoft account into my application. 
I am requesting in scope parameter with these permissions "profile User.Read Calendars.Read Calendars.ReadWrite"

**Below things works after successful login.**
1) It asks for the permission to grant 
2) Microsoft oauth2.0 login.
3) Profile picuture read.

But for some reason when i try to read "calendar" **I get 403 for only one account in whole tenant**. I have gone through below link for error description, but couldn't find out solution 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/errors

can anyone point me, where i need find solution for the above issue? Is it account issue or do I need to modify api request. Below api i am using to read calendar

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/calendarView?startDateTime=${sd}&endDateTime=${ed}

Comment: Is this user an external user? Or a personal Microsoft account? Also, do they have an O365 license?

Comment: Hi,  may I  know if your problem was solved ? If still have any problem, please let me know.

Comment: hi @HuryShen , the issue got resolved I cleared my past calendar events, there were lot of events on my account.

Answer (score 1):

For this problem, first you need to check if the token you got contains the correct permission, you can decode your token in this [page](https://jwt.io/). I test request this graph api with implicit grant flow, it works fine and I put my access token to decode we can see it contains the two calendar permissions which we expect.

[image]

Here I list some points which you need to pay attention to when you request this graph api:

**1.** As you mentioned in your question, you request in scope parameter with "Calendars.Read Calendars.ReadWrite" permissions, so did you add these two permissions to your AD application ? If you didn't add them, please add them in your AD application (**please add them in "Delegated permissions" but not "Application permissions", I test it if we add them in "Application permissions" it will show 403 error because implicit flow requires "Delegated permissions"**).
[image]

**2.** After add the two permissions, don't forget grant admin consent for them.
[image]